# My helloworld for C is compiling but the .exe file isn't running?

Tags: c, powershell, command-line, mingw

I coded this simple C Hello World program, but i don't know why it's not working in command line? I'm using MinGW C compiler which I downloaded per site instructions and I'm using Sublimetext for my text editor. I compiled the program fine it seems b/c the .exe file shows up, but when I try to run that file it prints

[image]

the problem seems pretty basic, my bad if it the question is amateur, just started trying to learn C.

Here's my code from Sublime text for it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i tried also just entering `helloworld` but that didn't work either

Comment: Type `.\helloworld` instead. PowerShell does not run executables in the current directory by default. (Look at the suggestion message.)

Comment: thanks so much!^^ @Bill_Stewart that's it, couldn't figure out that message for some reason

Comment: Messages are for help, use them.

Comment: In the future, please use copy/paste from your terminal into your question. It is impossible for expert users to search an image for expected warning or error text. Use the `{}` tool from the toolbox at the top left of edit dialog on selected text to keep the proper "programming" format. Glad you got a solution to your problem. Have you  read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ? These will help you write good Qs (except for the screen shot, this is a good one, so keep up the good work!) . Good luck.

Comment: Downvoting this because the solution is actually listed IN the error message.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the directory of the executable within PowerShell.  Your alternative is to launch the program through cmd.exe.

```
.\helloworld.exe
```

or

```
C:\Users\Zanel\OneDrive\documents\code\C\helloworld.exe
```

`.` represents current directory.

Comment: You even can type ./helloworld    In powershell - like on UNIX :).  Note forward slash and no .exe.

Comment: @ddbug only if that's the only helloworld.* file in the directory, otherwise I'm not sure how the behavior is defined.

Comment: Usually there won't be two files with same name in one directory :) But you can have one file named 'helloworld.exe' and one named 'helloworld' without ext. It would be a weird filesystem otherwise. Files with other exts (helloworld.c etc) won't be executed unless specified in PATHEXT.